# Checking for empty labels and populate based on textbox values

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Ok, I have 20 labels defined on my form and the text for these labels are being blanked out when the form loads. Labels are named "LabelValue1...LabelValue20"

On the form, is a textbox where a user will enter a numeric value. Upon hitting submit, I need to populate the first available label with this numeric value. The user may enter up to 20 different values at one time and I need to populate the next label with what ever value they entered a second time and so fourth.

Is there an easier way to code this then using a huge long if else endif statement?

Comment: could you use a listbox instead of 20 labels?

Comment: I could...as long as I can grab the value of each listbox item. A listbox was a second option I was thinking about.

Comment: yes, you can grab the value of each listbox item.  Check the help files for listbox or google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a list box would be more appropriate, if you need to do so, you can access the labels by name using the form's `Controls` collection:

```
Dim _currentLabel As Integer = 1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If _currentLabel <= 20 Then
        Dim lbl As Label = CType(Controls("LabelValue" & _currentLabel.ToString()), Label)
        lbl.Text = TextBox1.Text
        _currentLabel += 1
    End If
End Sub
```

To use a `ListBox` control, instead, you would simply need to do something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ListBox1.Items.Count < 20 Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

And then to read a particular item, you would do something like this:

```
Dim secondItem As String = CStr(ListBox1.Items(1))
```

Comment: I can see now why a listbox would be more approriate than a boat load of labels...thanks for your suggestion.